# Why am I getting the same value of x (-2147483648) irrespective of the different values of a, b and c I input?

Tags: c, syntax, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    
    printf("Input the values of a,b and c:\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    
    int x = b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c / 2*a);
    printf("x = %d",x);
           }
```

I tried changing the values of a, b and c but I keeping getting the same result for x.

Comment: What do you think `b^2` does?  C does not have a 'power-of' operator. Another problem is with the integer division. But anyway the position of `/ 2*a` in the (formula) arithmetic is incorrect.

Comment: ... *and* it should be `-b`. Please work with `double` too.

Comment: `double x = (-b ± sqrt((double)b * b - 4.0 * a * c) / (2.0 * a);`

Comment: You are just not providing the [right input](https://godbolt.org/z/YKb9914vK) for getting *other* results... Not that this would make the code more correct, though!

Comment: You should also be checking the return value from `scanf` to see if you really are getting all three values.  Otherwise you could be using garbage values without noticing it.  Hint:  *Always* check user input.  *Never* assume it's perfect with no typos or mistakes.

Comment: You need to consider, too, that you might run into trying to calculate a root from a negative value – unless you switch to complex numbers you won't get a valid result at all then! So: `double x = (double)(b*b - 4*a*c) / (a*2); if(x < 0) { /* no result! * } else { x = sqrt(x); }` (introducing double as late as possible; *only* valid if you don't need to fear overflow for input being small enough!!! – otherwise correct formula is given already). On the other hand you might want to get your *input* as double already, allowing to type e.g. `10.12`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with `b^2 - 4*a*c / 2*a`.  One is you're using integer arithmetic.  You should be using doubles.  Another is `b^2` is not `b` squared, it's the bitwise XOR of `b` with the constant `2`.  Learn to correctly use the C operators.  Another is your grouping.  You are missing parentheses in the numerator, so the first term is not part of the division, and you're also missing parentheses in the denominator, so instead of dividing by `2*a`, you are in fact dividing by `2` and *multiplying* by `a`.

Comment: And if you do want a floating point result, you need to declare `x` to be `double` and use the appropriate format in your `printf` call.

Comment: And a tip for testing: Provide statically compiled input (as I did in my link) – this spares you having to type in the same input again and again when you are testing modifications of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  printf("Input the values of a,b and c (integers only):\n");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

  double solution1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c) / (2.0 * a));
  double solution2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4.0 * a * c) / (2.0 * a));
  printf("Solutions: %f and %f\n", solution1, solution2);
}
```

There is no power operator in C, for powers of 2 just multiply the variable mwith itself.

You need to use parentheses in `4*a*c / 2*a` which otherwise is evaluated sequencially as `((4*a)*c)/2)*a`, IOW multiply 4 with a, then multiply with c, then divide by 2, then multiply with a, which is obviously not what you want.

You need `double`s instead of `int`s because the solutions are no necessarily integers. Also `4.0` and `2.0` in the expressions promote the results to `doubles` which is necessary to prevent rounding which occurs when the whole calcultion is dont with integer arithmetic.

There are still problems with this code because you need to check if `b * b - 4.0 * a * c` is negative, in that case the equation has no real solutions. I leave this to you as an exercise.